# Image ComboBox XAML not displaying properly during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to achieve a combo box with only images. The images doesn't need to be dynamic. I'm currently doing it this way:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="diceDot" Canvas.Left="244" Canvas.Top="10" Height="20" Width="40">
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Resources/dice1.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Resources/dice2.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Resources/dice3.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Resources/dice4.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Resources/dice5.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Resources/dice6.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
```

However, the images did not appear during runtime. It did render perfectly with the intended result during the design. I do not want a folder with the images to appear together with my executable file.

Error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Edited: Added error messages

**Problem fixed - Changing the build action to "Resource" and rebuilding the solution seemed to fix the problem.**

Comment: Go to the VS properties tab of the images, what "Build Action" do they have selected? It must be "Content" for those references to work.

Comment: I thought it supposed to be Resource or Embed Resource. However, I've switched to Content and it still doesn't display my images during runtime.

Comment: Look for errors in your output window. It sounds like the path to the images is wrong.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Yes. The output state that the path to the images is wrong.

Comment: @almulo Ahhh. The Build Action need to be "Resource" and not "Content".

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer After rebuilding and changing the build action to "Resource", it's working perfectly now. Thank you! :D

Comment: Weird, "Resource" usually requires you to use the full URI with assembly and all :P I guess there are exceptions... Glad you found it

Comment: Btw, @Ophitect, I suggest you put your solution as an answer, and select that answer as correct. So people can find it easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed - Changing the build action to "Resource" and rebuilding the solution seemed to fix the problem.